# Line style in QGIS

Tags: style, line

I want to create the following line in qgis[image]

But it conduced to a result not as expected[image]

Comment: You will need to give us some more information about the data. Are we discussing lines or polygons?

Comment: What about the result is unexpected?  You have a dashed line with a marker repeating every 30m.  Looks ok in the screenshot.  How would you like to change the result?

Comment: I see the problem, vertical lines are not on center lines of dashes. The only way is to do with SVG marker lines in the middle, or for a specific map scale try to guess the distance between the vertical lines on dashes lines.

Comment: What response has helped you?